# problem with compare properties in model class object in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using compare attribute for comparison fields in model class like below code

```
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
    [CompareAttribute("FruitName")]
    public string FruitNameCompare { get; set; }
```

but it causes error when I save object to database by db.savechanges()
I think it's because the object includes compare properties with null value whereas database table doesn't

error:
    Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

however it works fine when I remove compare properties

Comment: so have you checked the EntityValidationErrors? What is the error it specifies? Are `FruitName` and `FruitNameCompare` the same when in the object at the time you save it?

Comment: @GregH those are the same when sending to action.
I check validations by  jquery.validation.unobtrusive.
But at the save time FruitNameCompare is null.
Should I fill it as well?

Comment: if you're checking that theyre the same on the front end via jquery and not making use of the `FruitNameCompare` property on the server side, then im a little confused as to why that is in your server side model at all. I suspect if you check the EntityValidationErrors, it is complaining because your `FruitName` and `FruitNameCompare` are different. The `CompareAttribute` is going to enforce that they be the same in order to save the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FruitName` and `FruitNameCompare` properties must be the same because you've included a `[CompareAttribute("FruitName")]` annotation on your `FruitNameCompare`. This will enforce that the values for `FruitName` and `FruitNameCompare` must be the same.

The front end code hasn't been posted however I suspect it is a matter of `FruitNameCompare` not being included in the data sent from client side to server side. If you include this property as well, things should start working for you. If it is already being included, then set a breakpoint and ensure that the two properties' values match.

In the future, if you check the `EntityValidationErrors`, then you'll be given detailed information on what had failed and should have a good idea of where to go from there.

Comment: You where right.
I didn't fill FruitNameCompare in the post method.
It works now, Thanks. 
Am I doing the right job fo comparison? Or there is better ways to do that?

Comment: Usually I would either do the validation on the front end (like you're doing with jquery) or I'd do it on the backend with the annotations (like you're doing with the compare attribute) and not both but this is more preference than anything. If the validation logic changes then you'll have 2 spots to update instead of one and I don't personally see any benefit to checking in both places. If you only do it on the backend, then you'll have to implement something to check if the `ModelState` is valid and show any related error msgs on the client side

Comment: Shouldn I add [NotMapped] attribute as well or not?
If I don't, another column will add to database table named "FruitNameCompare" with null values.

Comment: You certainly can do that as it doesn't seem necessary to have a column to store `FruitNameCompare`. A better way to go about this would be to have your views use viewmodels instead of the raw EF entity. Then you would map data from your viewmodel to your raw model then save the raw model. Likewise on load you would retrieve the raw model then map it to the viewmodel and give the viewmodel to the view. So with this, you'd have the `FruitNameCompare` on the viewmodel but not on the raw EF model

Comment: Here's a very short beginner introduction for you as to why viewmodels are a good idea and commonly accepted as being a best practice: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223547/Three-Reasons-Why-You-Should-Use-View-Models

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful